# Shell script to move files into a hadoop cluster

Tags: shell, hadoop, hdfs

This may have been answered somewhere but I haven't found it yet.

I have a simple shell script that I'd like to use to move log files into my Hadoop cluster. The script will be called by Logrotate on a daily basis.

It fails with the following error: "/user/qradar: cannot open `/user/qradar' (No such file or directory)".

```
#!/bin/bash

#use today's date and time
day=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

#change to log directory
cd /var/log/qradar

#move and add time date to file name
mv qradar.log qradar$day.log

#load file into variable
#copy file from local to hdfs cluster

if [ -f qradar$day.log ]

then
    file=qradar$day.log
    hadoop dfs -put /var/log/qradar/&file   /user/qradar

else
    echo "failed to rename and move the file into the cluster" >> /var/log/messages

fi
```

The directory /user/qradar does exist and can be listed with the Hadoop file commands.
I can also manually move the file into the correct directory using the Hadoop file commands. Can I move files into the cluster in this manner? Is there a better way?

Any thoughts and comments are welcome.
Thanks

Comment: #change to log directory
cd /var/log

qradar.log resides in /var/log

Answer (score 4):

Is the `&file` a typo on in `hadoop dfs -put` line?

If not then this is likely your problem, you're running the command `hadoop dfs -put /var/log/qradar/` in the background (the ampersand runs the command in the background), then the command `file /user/qradar`, which the shell is looking for on the local path.

My guess is you meant for the following (dollar rather than ampersand):

```
hadoop dfs -put /var/log/qradar/$file /user/qradar
```

Comment: humbly I say yes it is a typo and tossing out the & for the $ fix the issue. So simple and so in front of me, many thanks for proofing.